# Change the URL but don't allow the browser to load that page

Tags: angular

I have a link and when clicking on it, I want the URL to be `/my-subpage` and the browser should not load that page.

Well, this works so far. See:

```html
<a href="/my-subpage" (click)="createCustomUrl($event, {'foo': 'bar'}, 'Page title', '/my-subpage')">
```

```js
createCustomUrl(e: Event, object: any, title: string, url: string): void {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.history.pushState(object, title, url);
}
```

Now when the URL is `/my-subpage`, I want to do something. How can I do this?

This is what I have tried:

```js
@HostListener('window:popstate')
onPopState() {
  console.log('Do something');
}
```

but nothing happens.

So what I am actually trying to do, is to listen to the event `popstate`. Well, in vanilla JS I could simply write:

```js
window.addEventListener('popstate', event => console.log('Do something'));
```

I don't know how to do this in Angular, so that's why I tried it with `@HostListener`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is probably not working, because you change the URL and expect from HostListener to return something at the same time. Well, `popstate` only detects the browser's forward and back buttons. So if you want to take an action, just put your code within your `createCustomUrl()` function.

However, you probably want to know the value of `foo`. In this case, your HostListener needs an event. So the following code should work, if you click on your custom link and then press the browser's back button and then the forward button:

```js
@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
onPopState(event: PopStateEvent) {
  if (event.state) {
    console.log(event.state.foo); // This returns 'bar'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
constructor(
  private router: Router
) {
  router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)  
  ).subscribe((event: NavigationStart) => {
     // You only receive NavigationStart events
    console.log(event.url);
  });
}
```

For a strict mode you can try this:

```
constructor(
  private router: Router
) {
  router.events.pipe(
    filter((event): event is NavigationEnd => event instanceof NavigationStart)  
  ).subscribe((event: NavigationStart) => {
     // You only receive NavigationStart events
    console.log(event.url);
  });
}
```

Comment: There must be something wrong with `(event: NavigationStart) => {`, since I get this error:  *TS2769: No overload matches this call.*

Comment: So try to console log all the events without the filter and choose the one that helps you the most

Comment: Another solution that can work is to change the filter row that way:
      `filter((event): event is NavigationEnd => event instanceof NavigationEnd)`

Comment: I tried the same but I get this error: *R3InjectorError(AppModule)[Router -> Router -> Router]: NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!*

Comment: Please use this in the app module:

`RouterModule.forRoot(
  [
    { path: "", component: AppComponent}
  ]
)`

Comment: My problem has already been solved. Thanks anyway!